# How to hide the button image when i tap the button,ios

Tags: animation, button, show-hide, imagebutton, tap

Am pretty new to Animation development.Am trying to make a fun application in which i took three buttons.One of that button contains the background as image.The functionality of the other two buttons is when i tap the second button,it has to display the UITextField at the top of that button exactly.
I hiddened that UITextView with the help of hidden functionality.Now when i tapped the second button,the first button with the help of animation i created will be placed at the top of the second button.And same procedure is also applied to the third button.When i tapped one button,the image button is dropped on the top of the tapped button and then UITextField is shown.
Now what i want to do is i want to hide the button image when the UITextField is shown?Please some One help me and what to do in the next step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On click of the second/third button, you need to clear the background image of button one. This is what i understood, and if my understanding is correct, then you need to call [buttonOne setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal] when you are clicking the button (2 or 3).